# Flex items are not shrinking

Tags: html, css

I am trying to shrink upload-container and img-vector when the screen size is reduced but it seems that the upload container is not shrinking in size. I am new to CSS and I am unable to figure out the problem.

[Link to my pen](https://codepen.io/adishrtv/pen/poNLWpd)

```css
body,
#main-container,
.upload-container,
.drop-zone {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body,
.upload-container,
.drop-zone {
    flex-direction: column;
}

#main-container {
    background-color: green;
    justify-content:space-around;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.image-vector {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    background: url(https://picsum.photos/200) no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
}

.upload-container {
    background: #17191c;
    border-radius: 25px;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Comment: I would try to help, but I'm not sure that I understand your problem. Could you explain it better?

Comment: In the main-container, there are 2 things - upload-container and image-vector. I have set the main-container display flex, and in both upload-container and image-vector, I am writing flex-shrink: 1. But, when I reduce the screen size, their sizes do not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added the following code in Responsive Mode. With `flex-flow: row wrap;` I changed the `flex-direction` to `row` and `flex-warp` to `warp` break in overflow mode.

```
#main-container,
.upload-container,
.drop-zone {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --main-bg-color: #212429;
  --light-blue: #3a9aed;
  --border-color: #3a9aed;
  --container-width: 500px;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: var(--main-bg-color);
  height: 98vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}

body,
#main-container,
.upload-container,
.drop-zone {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body,
.upload-container,
.drop-zone {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 55px;
}

#main-container {
  background-color: green;
  /* justify-content:space-around; */
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.footer-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 80%;
}

.image-vector {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.upload-container {
  background: #17191c;
  border-radius: 25px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.drop-zone {
  width: var(--container-width);

  min-height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed var(--border-color);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  transition: 0.2s all ease-in;
}

/* will be added when user drags */
.drop-zone.dragged {
  background: var(--main-bg-color);
  border-color: #0288d1;
}

.drop-zone input {
  display: none;
}

.icon-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
}

.icon-container img {
  width: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.icon-container .center {
  z-index: 10;
}
.icon-container .right,
.icon-container .left {
  filter: grayscale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.dragged .center {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
.dragged .right {
  transform: rotate(10deg) scale(0.9) translateX(20px);
}
.dragged .left {
  transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(0.9) translateX(-20px);
}

.title {
  font-size: large;
}

#browseBtn {
  color: #2196f3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* uploading progress styles */
.progress-container {
  border: 2px solid var(--main-bg-color);
  width: var(--container-width);
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.progress-container .inner-container {
  margin: 10px 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.progress-container .percent-container {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.progress-container .bg-progress {
  position: absolute;
  background: var(--main-bg-color);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 250ms linear;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.progress-container .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #03a9f4;
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
}

/* sharing container style */
.sharing-container {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: var(--container-width);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.sharing-container p {
  text-align: center;
}

.sharing-container .expire {
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.sharing-container .input-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sharing-container .input-container input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px dashed var(--border-color);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #17191c;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.sharing-container img {
  height: 22px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 7px;
  top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #17191c;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.email-container form {
  border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.email-container,
.send-btn-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.email-container label {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.email-container input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--border-color);
  height: 19px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.email-container input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.email-container .filed {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
}

.send-btn-container button {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: #3a9aed;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toast {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 60px);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: var(--light-blue);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0px 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transition: transform ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.image-vector {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/200") no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

.show.toast {
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  :root {
    --container-width: 320px;
  }
 body,
#main-container,
.upload-container,
.drop-zone {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

  .email-container .filed {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .email-container .filed {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">EZ Sharing</div>
<main id='main-container'>
  <section class="upload-container">
    <form action="">
      <div class="drop-zone">
        <div class="icon-container">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" draggable="false" class="center" alt="File Icon" />
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" draggable="false" class="left" alt="File Icon" />
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" draggable="false" class="right" alt="File Icon" />
        </div>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
        <div class="title">
          Drop your Files here or,
          <span id="browseBtn">Browse</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div class="bg-progress"></div>

      <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="status">Uploading...</div>
        <div class="percent-container">
          <span class="percentage" id="progressPercent">0 %</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sharing-container">
      <p class="expire">Link expires in 24 hrs</p>

      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" id="fileURL" readonly />
        <img src="./copy-icon.svg" id="copyURLBtn" alt="copy to clipboard icon" />
      </div>

      <p class="email-info">Or Send via Email</p>
      <div class="email-container">
        <form id="emailForm">
          <div class="filed">
            <label for="fromEmail">Your email</label>
            <input type="email" autocomplete="email" required name="from-email" id="fromEmail" />
          </div>

          <div class="filed">
            <label for="toEmail">Receiver's email</label>
            <input type="email" required autocomplete="receiver" name="to-email" id="toEmail" />
          </div>
          <div class="send-btn-container">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="image-vector"></div>
</main>
<div class="toast">Sample message</div>
<div class="footer-container">
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" alt="Facebook" src="./github-logo.svg" width="50" height="50" />
  </a>
  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <a href="/" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" alt="Facebook" src="./linkedin.svg" width="50" height="50" />
  </a>
  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <a href="">
    <img border="0" alt="Facebook" src="./facebook.svg" width="50" height="50" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you did to solve the issue? So that the OP and others would understand it!

Comment: Yes, of course I will add a description.

Comment: @anita shrivastava I changed the code. Use my new code. It is both cleaner and simpler and I did not change the original code at all.